# What is the etiquette for editing a criticized Answer?

Tags: discussion

There have been a few cases where my answers received negative (yet constructive) criticism.  Then when I'm thinking about an answer, someone else posts a better answer which brings up additional dimensions. The question I have is whether it is proper to keep editing to make my answer even better, or should I "take my lumps" and let it slide?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always improve your answer. If you get ideas on how to improve from other answers, cite your sources and move on.

Comment: Yep. Just mention you got the idea from another user.